# usage of ('/') in the following django code

Tags: django, django-views

I started a todo app tutorial and having a problem into fully understanding code in this part of it:

```
def index(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.all()

    form= TaskForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
    return redirect('/')
```

'''
just the part which used redirect('/') , what is the meaning of this sign (( ('/') )) and if you could explain to me why is it important to specify for the app that if the request method is POST do the following moves?

I just found this in the list template :

```
<form method="POST" action="/">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return redirect('/')` means that you are being redirected to the root url. If your domain is `http://example.org` and you are in `http://example.org/example/example-post/` you are being redirected to `http://example.org/`.

Absolute paths in urls start with the `/`, and relative paths dont.

If you are in `http://example.org/example/example-post/` and your form is like this `<form method="POST" action="/example">` you are being redirected to `http://example.org/example/`, but if it says this `<form method="POST" action="example">`, the next url will be `http://example.org/example/example-post/example/`.

Comment: couldnt we just use "" like in path to do the job instead of putting '/' as an absloute URL?

Answer (score 1):

Since the '/' is already answered above I will answer your question about why if a method is post Django create a new form of TaskForm the Reason is that the if condition to check if the given method is post then you are filling values and request.post will transfer these value to the form you can see in the url when filling a form the url will look someone like this 127:5000:username=''%password ='' this is the data from the request.

Comment: Im not quite sure about what you just said, could you explain it in another way or in more details?

Comment: In a nutshell, this line form = TaskForm(request.POST), create a new Task of type TaskForm and it fetches the data inside the post method (request.POST) and this Line if form.is_valid():, check if a form is valid, it's up to you how do you validate your data in the forms.py, if the data is valid then it should be saved in the database form.save(), why this happens after a post method not a get, because post as a http request used when inserting new objects or data, hope this helps

Comment: thanks alot for them help i just thought POST & GET are just inorder to show type of sending data in security or just as a normal way but you are saying that one additional job which POST method do , is we can use it in http request inorder to instert new objects or data , am i right?

Comment: yes post request carries the data entered by the user :=)